# Alternative to Icon Menu/ PopOver Menu in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui for a project and I got stuck in using menus. Basically I want to select multiple values from the menu which DropDown does not support. And other menus don't support OnChange. So what should I use in order to select multiple values(these values are sort of filters for a table so they can't be normal lists)

Comment: I'm guessing [this](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/1956) is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and still not sure about the onChange support 
how about using  [Toggle switch](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/toggle)